# What is the best way to go about building a price comparison site?

Tags: wordpress, api, comparison

Hi I have a business idea for a price comparison website. I have limited knowledge in web design and development so I thought I would ask the experts before doing anything else! I have heard about API's and all this but I have also read that it is possible with WordPress so I'm not sure what way to go. All help appreciated and thanks!

Comment: Your question is too broad. Saying "possible with Word Press" is irrelevant. WordPress is a website creation tool. You have a website creation idea that can be created in many different tools. You really should look into consulting with professionals in the field as there is a lot more to what your asking than just what tool to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you have limited knowledge in web design and development, maybe you would be better off with a standard theme that has the functionality that you need already built in to it?

I have the same problem and I recently delivered a dating site for a client using the dating theme from PremiumPress.com. They have a price comparison theme that looks quit well too.

That way, you don't have to worry about the technical part, you just have to customize the look and feel of the theme.